# Change label backcolor when click

Tags: c#, event-handling, label, backcolor

Hello guys i have a easy problem here, if i click the `label1` it will change back Color to Red but my default Back Color is transparent.

```
   private void label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

       label1.BackColor = Color.Red;
   }

   private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       label2.BackColor = Color.Red;
   }
```

what if i click the label again i want it to change color to transparent, how do i code that? Thank you in advance! :D

```
label.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

Comment: if statement would do that

Comment: yeah but how do i do that i tried `if(label1.click == true)` haha and i feel silly coding that.

Comment: Gleng has done that for you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19498816/2530848

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to flip the color based on its current value. That can be done by doing:

```
label1.BackColor = label1.BackColor == Color.Red ? Color.Transparent : Color.Red;
```

The above is a `conditional operator` and is basically just shorthand for an if/else statement,

```
if (label1.BackColor == Color.Red)
    label1.BackColor = Color.Transparent
else
    label1.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: @MarilouMagat I've updated my answer for clarity. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just add an `if` statement:

```
private void label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(label1.BackColor == Color.Red)
    {
         label1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }
    else
    {
        label1.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: Initially `BackColor` will not be `Color.Transparent`

Comment: It says in the question the default background color is transparent, but I have altered my answer all the same

Answer (score 0):

```
  private void label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Label label1 = (Label)sender;
       if (label1.BackColor == Color.Red)
            label1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
       else
            label1.BackColor = Color.Red;
   }
```

by using the line   Label label1 = (Label)sender; You can apply the same event for all your labels.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( label.BackColor == Color.Red)
{
     label.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
}else
{
    label.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```